# DeferredTreeContentManager in e4?

Tags: eclipse, treeview, rcp, deferred, e4

I´m wondering how to implement the DeferredTreeContentManager (org.eclipse.e4.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager) in an e4 rcp?

I googled a little but I only saw some e3-concerning threads.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean `org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager` (no e4 in the package) this is not usable by a pure e4 application because it has dependencies on the 3.x workbench.

The only suggestion I have seen is to copy the source and try to remove the 3.x dependencies.

Comment: Jep I ment that without e4 =D. Thanks!